# How can I calculate the center of multiple polygons in Google Maps Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Let's say I have an array of polygons, which contains a bunch of lat/long coordinates used to draw these areas on a map:

```
// These polygons are just an example to illustrate structure, they are not my actual polygons

var polygons = [ 
    [
       {lat: 1, lng: 2},
       {lat: 3, lng: 4},
       {lat: 5, lng: 6},
       {lat: 1, lng: 2},
    ],
    [
       {lat: 7, lng: 8},
       {lat: 9, lng: 10},
       {lat: 11, lng: 12},
       {lat: 7, lng: 8},
    ],
];
```

**When initializing the map, How do I set the initial viewport of the map to be centered around all polygons?**

Here is an image illustrating what I mean:

[image: How I want the map to behave]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could construct a [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds) object.  For each point in your polygons, extend that Bounds object to include that point.  Then update the map to fit those bounds.

Something like this:

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < polygons[i].length; j++) {
        bounds.extend(polygons[i][j]);
    }
}

map.fitBounds(bounds);
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
```

One issue you might have is I'm not sure if the `bounds.extend` will work with the `{lat: 1, lng: 2}` format for your points. You may have to construct LatLng objects instead.

In which case it would be:

```
bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(polygons[i][j].lat, polygons[i][j].lng));
```

Comment: `LatLngBounds`  has a method `.extend(LatLng)`. Simply iterate all points in all polygons and supply them to the `extend` method of a new `LatLngBounds` instance. You'll end up with an object you can use with `map.fitBounds(LatLngBounds)`.

Answer (score -1):

Just a snippet from my old project

```
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles);

var mapOptions = {
    //backgroundColor: '#000',
    //draggable:false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    overviewMapControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    rotateControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    zoomControl:false,
    noClear: true,
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.1, 122), //<----- set the center here
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);`enter code here`
```

Take a look at center property within the code above

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.1, 122), //<----- set the center here
```